# pandas filter group by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like to filter results in this query, thus having only results >1 in table, if possible in a single line of code.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
df= pd.DataFrame({'Product':['A','B', 'C','A','B','D'],
                  'Age':[28,39,21,50,35,43], 
                  'Country':['USA','India','Germany','USA','India','India']
                 })
print(df.head())
table=df.groupby(['Product','Country'])['Age'].count()
table
```

Comment: `table[table.values>1]`?

Comment: Could you specify your question more precisely? All age values are > 1, so it's not entirely clear what the issue is or whether this is a hypothetical question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
df= pd.DataFrame({'Product':['A','B', 'C','A','B','D'],
                  'Age':[28,39,21,50,35,43], 
                  'Country':['USA','India','Germany','USA','India','India']
                 })

table=df.groupby(['Product','Country'])['Age'].count().reset_index(name='count')
table1 = table[table["count"]>1]
table1
```

you can filter the count column f. e. like this. You can also change this to a single line like:

```
table=df.groupby(['Product','Country'])['Age'].count().reset_index(name='count')[table["count"]>1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's chain `query` method:

```
table = (df.groupby(['Product','Country'])['Age'].count()
           .reset_index(name='Count')
           .query('Count > 1'))
table
```

Output:

```
  Product Country  Count
0       A     USA      2
1       B   India      2
```